# populate array value from li elements, remove hidden li from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a map with populated with markers (pins) represented by li of an ul  (each li has 2 divs defining lat & long data). These li are sorted into categories from a drop-down menu (select tag) with hide/show. When the select value changes, I want only the visible li markers to populate the map.

I need help with my code to remove hidden markers when the select value changes. Currently, all markers remain on the map when li are hidden. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var licounter = 0;

    $("#mapContent ul li").each(function(index) {
      licounter ++;
      if ($("#mapContent ul li:hidden")){
        markers.splice(licounter, 1);
        licounter --;
      };
    });
});
});
```

Here is the full code if that helps:

```
var mapStart = new google.maps.LatLng(41.8819,-87.823);
var markers;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
markers = new Array();
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 6,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  center: mapStart
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);



$("#mapContent ul li").each(function(index) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng($(this).children(".marker_long").text(), $(this).children(".marker_lat").text()),
    map: map,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: 'images/marker.png',
    title : $(this).children(".marker_title").text()
    });

    markers.push(marker);
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var licounter = 0;

$('select[name="mapCat"]').change(function(){

    var chosenCat =$(this).val();       
    $('#mapContent ul li').hide();
    $('#mapContent ul li.'+chosenCat).show();
    if (chosenCat == 'opt0'){
        $('#mapContent ul li').show();
    };


    $("#mapContent ul li").each(function(index) {
      licounter ++;
      if ($("#mapContent ul li:hidden")){
        markers.splice(licounter, 1);
        licounter --;
      };
    });
});
});

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, you need to decide what the hook will be on your filter. For example, something that evaluates to yes/no or a specific value...

Then you can assign that value to your marker(s). For example, when you are creating your markers:

```
// Inside the for loop to create your markers.
marker.set('id', results[i].id);
```

This will give you some sort of hook that you can compare against.

You will need to put all of your markers into an array.

```
var markerArray = [];
...
// Other marker setup.
markerArray.push(marker);
```

For your filter (select input) you will need something like this:

```
$(selector).on('change', function() {
    var filter = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i < that.plotMarkers.length; i++)
    {
        if (markers[i].YOUR_HOOK === filter || filter === '')
        {
            markers[i].setVisible(true);
        }
        else
        {
            markers[i].setVisible(false);
        }
    }
});
```

In a nutshell, you need to use "setVisible" for your markers.
If you are using clusters, then you need to look into "markerCluster.setIgnoreHidden" - using [MarkerClusterrPlus](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html)